# Remove random generated characters from a string to display the word in clear text

Tags: php

I have this function to put some random characters into a string:

```
function random($string) {

    $chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
    $shuffle_start = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 6);
    $shuffle_end = substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 6);
    $letters = str_split($string);
    $str = '';

    $count = count($letters);
    foreach($letters AS $l) {
        $count--;
        $str .= $l;
        if($count) {
            $str .= substr(str_shuffle($chars), 0, 5);
        }
    }

    return $shuffle_start . $str . $shuffle_end;

}
```

This function prints this from the string "hello": `aApi3VhKJrDjeAbCkalprX7ll7N0Qjo3qymiw`. Now, I want to remove the random characters from the string so the word "hello" are being clearly seen.

How can I do this?

Comment: lets just consider that how human can do this? if so, we can create an algorithm

Comment: `function random($string) { return $string; }` ?

Comment: @JasonOOO Easy! `aApi3V h KJrDj e AbCka l prX7l l 7N0Qj o 3qymiw`. Can this be fixed? If so, how can I fix it? How should the algorithm looks like?

Comment: there is no difference between a,h, o, l how we knew that?! I think this is not possible, try to make your life easier.

Comment: But it is possible. dev-null-dweller solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move backwards. Strip 6 characters form start and end, and then get every sixth character

```
function unrandom($str){
    $base = substr($str, 6, strlen($str)-12);
    $ret = '';
    for($i=0;$i < strlen($base); $i+=6) {
        $ret .= substr($base, $i,1);
    }
    return $ret;
}
```